# When designing an encryption algorithm what are the key factors that determine what the algorithm would do?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm looking into a little project of designing my own symmetric crypt algorithm. It will be for mainly file encryption.
What is the design process for such a project?

Comment: Hopefully constructive criticism: if you have to ask this question, then more than likely your encryption will be useless. To put it another way, you'll be the embodyment of Schneier's Law: "Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break."

Comment: Don't do it, if you have not already enough background in cryptography (i.e. analyzed some other algorithms, read lots of papers, etc.), otherwise your algorithm will be trivial to break. Use an established algorithm, if possible also an established protocol/file format.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive criticism, I have had many the same feedback before. The thing is, this is a project, and I do not visualize releasing this to the outer public.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First lesson - don't.

Second lesson - learn [cryptanalysis](http://www.schneier.com/paper-self-study.html). If you aren't aware of how crypto schemes are already being broken, how will you assess how "strong" or "weak" your own algorithms are.

The self study paper I linked to above is aging a bit however. There are newer attacks (such as the recent bi-clique attack against AES) which won't be covered there.

---

There's also a fledgling [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site, which may be a better place to ask questions, if you actually intend to study crypto seriously (rather than "I've invented the best crypto system ever, nobody will ever be able to crack it").

Answer (score 2):

Build an algorithm that is resistant to...

Known plain-text attacks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack

Chosen plain-text attacks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen_plaintext_attack

Differential cryptoanalysis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_cryptanalysis

Linear cryptoanalysis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_cryptanalysis

My specific suggestion is that you start with a cryptographically secure random number generator (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator), seed said generator with your symmetric encryption key and work from there avoiding the attack vectors above.

Comment: Thanks, this is very specific and I value it alot